# Resize image jquery в модальном окне

Tags: jquery, bootstrap

Вставляю ресайз изображение на jQuery в модальное окно, сам ресайз работает, но выделенная область идет за модальным окном.

модальное окно делаю через bootstrap,
как сделать, что бы нормальное работал ресайз в модальном окне? или какое модальное окно посоветуете?

Answer (score 1):

попробуй [Fancybox](http://fancybox.net/)

Comment: пробовал другие модальные окна, так же.